# Additional column in the intermediate table in many to many replationship in jpa

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have two classes Game and Team which have many-to-many relationship between them.

Game:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "GAME")
public class Game extends Model {

 @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinTable(name="GAME_TEAM", 
                joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="GAME_ID")}, 
                inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="TEAM_ID")})
private List<Team> teams = new ArrayList<Team>();

public List<Team> getTeams() {
    return teams;
}

public void setTeams(List<Team> teams) {
    this.teams = teams;
}
}
```

Team:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TEAM")

public class Team extends Model {


@Column(name = "TEAM_NAME")
private String teamName;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "team", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private Set<Player> player = new LinkedHashSet<Player>();

@ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="teams") 
private Set<Game> games; 

public Set<Player> getPlayer() {
    return player;
}

public void setPlayer(Set<Player> player) {
    this.player = player;
}

public Set<Game> getGames()  
{  
    return games;  
}  

public void setGames(Set<Game> games) {
    this.games = games;
}

public String getTeamName() {
    return teamName;
}

public void setTeamName(String teamName) {
    this.teamName = teamName;
}
```

There is a third intermediate table which between these two classes GAME_TEAM which has the team_id, game_id which are foreign keys to the ids from game and team class. So whenever I am updating team and game, I automatically update the game_team.

Ok. Good. Now what is the problem? I have a third column WON_BY which also has to be updated. Without this additional third column, I did not have to create the third class GameTeam.

To update the third column which is not a foreign key, should I create an entity class for the intermediate table? If so what kind of approach or annotation should I use?

Comment: and where is this in your Java class model? Ahh, it isn't. So design your model to include it and you'll find what you need to do

Answer (score 5):

> You need to have a separate entity class to persist your 'WON_BY', and
>   you need to re-factor your existing entity classes a bit, since the
>   solution is quite big refer the below sample example, which will
>   definitely solves your problem.

http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-association-with-extra-columns-in-join-table-example

Comment: Adding cascading on an intermediate table might not be a good idea in most use cases (at least for CascadeType.REMOVE)